# MethodError no method matching similar

Tags: julia

I wanted to write a DiffEq solver code, when I stumbled into this MethodError:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching similar(::Float64, ::Type{Float64})
```

I don't even know where could be the problem.

I wanted to solve a shape of a rotating chain, however when I ran the code it gave me the MethodError, which can be seen above.
I am so sorry if it has been asked before, but I couldn't find the solution.

```
using OrdinaryDiffEq, Plots, DifferentialEquations, StaticArrays

#Initials
y0 = [0.1]
dy0 = [0.0]

xspan = (0.0,100.0)

#Problem
function rot_chain(ddy, dy, y, p, x)
    ddy = -(50.0 + 9.81 * dy) * (1 + 1 / (dy ^ 2)) / (50.0 * x + 9.81 * y)
end

#Define the Problem
prob = SecondOrderODEProblem(rot_chain, dy0, y0, xspan)

#Solution
sol = solve(prob)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `dy` and `y` are vectors, I think you want to perform element-by-element computation.
In this case, use the dot operation `dy_square = dy .^ 2`.
And for a big formula, you can use the dot macro `@.`:

```
function rot_chain(ddy, dy, y, p, x)
    ddy = @. -(50.0 + 9.81 * dy) * (1 + 1 / (dy ^ 2)) / (50.0 * x + 9.81 * y)
end
```